# How to use Puppeteer to get the specified element

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

One page has two divs:

```
<div class='class1'>...</div>

<div class='class1 class2'>...</div>
```

Use the code below:

```
let result = await page.$$eval('div.class1', nodes => {...})
```

get the two kinds divs above, but I just want to get the divs(class='class1') .

How can I do that?

Comment: you want  only the first element ? or any element with `class="class1"`

Comment: I want all the elements class="class1" && class != 'class2', and it solved below, thx @Vaviloff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args), `page.$$eval` uses `document.querySelectorAll` to find elements with the passed selector, so we can tell it **not** to retrieve *class2*:

```
let result = await page.$$eval('div.class1:not(.class2)', nodes => {...})
```

But obviously this doesn't scale well: you'll need to keep track of all of the **other** classes that are not supposed to be chosen and constantly update the code.

It's better to filter only those nodes that have exactly the necessary class name:

```
let result = await page.$$eval('.class1', nodes => 
    nodes.filter(node => node.className === "class1").map(node => node.textContent)
);
```

Note how we don't have to convert a nodeList to an array here (for example with `[...nodes]` or `Array.from(nodes)`) and can use filter and map right away. That's because `page.$$eval` conveniently does it for us.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works and I get more knowledge from your answer!